# Magento 2 - Add To Cart Button Direct To Product Details With Non Required Options

Tags: magento2, custom-options, addtocart

I am on Magento 2.1.1 and I am trying to change the Add to Cart button behaviour in Grid / List Views.

At the moment, the add to cart button only directs the customer to the product detail page if there is a required custom option. If all of the custom options are non-required (as they have to be on my site), then the add to cart button simply adds the product to the cart.

I need the Add to Cart button to redirect the customer to the product detail page if there are any un-required custom options for the product - and for it to add to cart if there are no options at all.

I have read a question on the same topic for an earlier version of Magento, but it is different in Magento 2. I assume the answer lies somewhere in templates/product/list.phtml

I hope someone can help. Thanks.